# Linux system to manage configurations of servers?

Tags: linux, configuration, system-administration

I need a software to manage configurations of linux servers in one central location. It should be able to push changes to servers automaticly. Version control would be an advantage...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/) (as [matli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23896/matli) suggested) and [Cfengine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfengine), which are both listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet)

Answer (score 0):

There's also Chef and bcfg2. If you're a Java guy, Control Tier is nice. There are some new projects in the python space to address the issue as well: Kokki, Overmind, Edison.

They all do essentially the same thing just in different ways. If you're a ruby developer, Chef is going to feel VERY familiar. If you aren't a developer and don't care about the language, puppet, while written in Ruby, abstracts it all out into a DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Bluepring and Blueprint I/O. Blueprint is an open-source tool for figuring out what's been done to a server. Packages, file modifications and source installs are detected and packaged up in a reusable formtat - a blueprint. Blueprint I/O is a tools for moving blueprints to another server. Together, they make for a drop dead simple configuration management tool. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint (Blueprint @ Github)

https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint-io (Blueprint I/O @ Github)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still might be helpful to you: We are releasing ConfigChief, a hosted central configuration repository with versioning, audit, access control which turns the problem around by pulling configuration from the server rather than pushing it which is the solution provided by Puppet and the rest.

You can signup for a beta at http://woot.configchief.com if you like.